# Silverlight control stays on top of div? Can't use Windowless mode and z-index is not working

Tags: asp.net, css, silverlight

On the following [website](http://spectrumbridge.com/udrs/search.aspx), when I click the dropdown for the Login at the upper right, it is displayed behind the silverlight map.  I can't use windowless mode because this would disable scrolling and menus on the map. I have tried putting the z-index everywhere, but I can't seem get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not be possible without using windowless mode. The Silverlight plugin is going to get rendered on top. You will just have to put the map lower to give the login more space or else deal with the limitations of windowless mode.

Comment: Don't think so, Silverlight is basically rendered by itself in a layer above the rest of the browser content. When windowless mode is used the rendering is passed off to the browser to blend the frames, resulting in the performance hit but allowing you to mix the content in a seamless way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the windowless and transparent background params?

```
<param name="background" value="transparent" />
<param name="windowless" value="true" />
```

See http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/16731/55689.aspx for more information.

Comment: This does not work. I mentioned I can't use windowless because it disables zooming in the map and the menus.

Comment: @Xaisoft Sorry. Then there's probably no way to solve this, it's just the same thing as with flash and wmode. Try to redesign the login form so that it doesn't intersect the map...

Comment: ok, thanks for helping out, I'm still trying to figure it out, lol, hoping that it will suddenly work.